# Iterating every row and check if column is NaN in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a scenario where I want to iterate through every row and in each row , looking for NaN in 3rd column.

Basically in my input dataset, the third column is NaN after every few rows.
So whenever I hit NaN in third column , I want to copy the value in 1st column in that row in all the rows below this row , till I again encounter a row with 3rd column as NaN.

In order to do this , I want to see if 3rd Column is NaN or not in every row.

Any relevant pointers will be much appreciated.

Regards,
Arun

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Using [pd.Series.isnull](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isnull.html) method on your third column to get all rows where your data is NaN then iterating with a for loop should do the trick